# nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:49

Tags: nginx

Iam facing with this error,

Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:49 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

This is my nginx.conf file:

## For more information on configuration, see:

```
  2 #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  3 #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
  4
  5 user nginx;
  6 worker_processes auto;
  7 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  8 pid /run/nginx.pid;
  9
 10 # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
 11 include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
 12
 13 events {
 14     worker_connections 1024;
 15 }
 16
 17 http {
 18     log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
 19                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
 20                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
 21
 22     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
 23
 24     sendfile            on;
 25     tcp_nopush          on;
 26     tcp_nodelay         on;
 27     keepalive_timeout   65;
 28     types_hash_max_size 4096;
 29
 30     include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 31     default_type        application/octet-stream;
 32
 33     # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
 34     # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
 35     # for more information.
 36     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 37     include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
 38
 39     # server {
 40     #     listen       80;
 41     #    listen       [::]:80;
 42     #    server_name  _;
 43     #    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
 44
 45         # Load configuration files for the default server block.
 46         include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 47
 48         error_page 404 /404.html;
 49         location = /404.html {
 50         }
 51
 52         error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 53         location = /50x.html {
 54         }
 55     }
 56
 57 # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
 58 #
 59 #    server {
 60 #        listen       443 ssl http2;
 61 #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
 62 #        server_name  _;
 63 #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
 64 #
 65 #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
 66 #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
 67 #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
 68 #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
 69 #        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
 70 #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 71 #
 72 #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
 73 #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 74 #
 75 #        error_page 404 /404.html;
 76 #            location = /40x.html {
 77 #        }
 78 #
 79 #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 80 #            location = /50x.html {
 81 #        }
 82 #    }
 83
 84 }
 85
```

Comment: The first five lines of your main `server {` block are commented out.

Comment: Are you referring to the server on line 59? 



 59 #    server {

Comment: wow~~!!  solved it Thank you~ ceejayoz :D